# Менять значение циклом в replace(regexp)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
var a = "number one: {{one}}. number two: {{two}}";

function renderTemplate(template) {
  var reg = /({{\w*}})/g;
  return template.replace(reg, function(str){
      for(let i = 1; i < 3; i++){
          return i;
      }

  })
};   
renderTemplate(a);
```

Надо что бы в строку перезаписывалось 1 и 2, а записывается только 1(так как цикл сразу возвращает первое значение i). Как исправить ?

Я хочу такой вывод --> number one: 1. number two: 2
А получается такой --> number one: 1. number two: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл *внутри* функции замены не нужен, так как эта функция и так вызывается для каждого из соответствий.

Нужно просто по найденной строке вернуть строку для замены, для этого можно использовать дополнительный объект:

```
var map = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2
};
```

И немного поменять регулярное выражение, чтобы в группу попадало значение *внутри* скобок.

```
/{{(\w*)}}/g
```

Теперь, первым параметром в функцию замены будет приходить полное соответствие: `{{one}}`, вторым - значение внутри группы: `one`.

При этом тело функции замены выродится в получение значения объекта по ключу

```
return map[str];
```

Пример в сборе

```js
var a = "number one: {{one}}. number two: {{two}}";

function renderTemplate(template) {
  var reg = /{{(\w*)}}/g;
  var map = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2
  };

  return template.replace(reg, function(_, str) {
    return map[str];
  })
};
console.log(renderTemplate(a));
console.log(renderTemplate("number two: {{two}}. number one: {{one}}"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы каждый раз перезапускаете цикл. Вынесите инициализацию переменной

```
function renderTemplate(template) {
  var reg = /({{\w*}})/g;
  var i = 1;
  return template.replace(reg, function(str){
          return i++;
  })
};
```

UPdate:

Не забудьте добавить проверку на существование свойства

```
function renderTemplate(template) {
  var reg = /{{(\w*)}}/g;
  var c = { one:1, two:2 }

  return template.replace(reg, function(full,str) {
          return c[str];
  })
};
```

Comment: лучше добавить объект, в котором ключами будут искомые значения, а значениями на что менять, иначе если в строка поменяется порядок one и two - вывод все равно останется тем же

Comment: @Grundy Вполне могу вообразить, судя по коду, что содержание полей в исходном тексте неизвестно, а просто, что встретится, надо поменять на последовательные номера

Comment: @Grundy А можете код написать плиз ???